# rspec test failing although test functionally working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a few tests for simple tags like  or  the results are correct but the rspec tests are failing. I am able to validate that the output is correct using `save_and_open_page` but I can't understand why the rspec tests don't view this as valid output!?

Can you spot what's wrong? Thanks!

**Spec Code**

```
    it { save_and_open_page; should have_selector('title', text: "CredSimple - Sign in") }
```

**Resulting Failure Messages**

```
Failure/Error: it { save_and_open_page should have_selector('title', text: "CredSimple - Sign in") }
     expected css "title" with text "CredSimple - Sign in" to return something
```

The save_and_open_page confirms that the page has the title that the test is seeking:

```
<title>CredSimple - Sign in</title>
```

Comment: check `page.body` and `page.body.should have_selector(...)`

Comment: Like this:    `it { save_and_open_page; page.body.should have_selector('title', text: "CredSimple - Sign in") }` ?

Comment: Try breaking it out into a full example and calling .should on `page`